# correcting navigation between VCs in existing app

Tags: ios, xcode, navigation, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a fairly simple app thats a game for small children. There is a main screen and 5 separate levels. 3 of the 5 levels are made up of more than one VC where actions take place in the first VC in that row then code calls a modal segue to the next one in the line and so on till it reaches the end of the row and a modal segue is called linking back to the main screen. The levels that have only one VC just perform actions then segue back to the main VC.

Every segue in the app in modal.
Also every page (VC) has a home button that will segue to the main page if pressed

I set this all up in the StoryBoard and visually everything works as Id expect but when adding sound I realized that there seems to be a major problem.

If I now understand correctly (and maybe I dont) modal segues dont actually replace the current VC with the newly requested one but rather slide the newly requested one over top the original and make it the visible display.

Currently I go from main to level 1. Level 1 does some stuff and plays some sounds that repeat via a timer. If I segue back to main visually everything is fine except the sounds being played by the timers in level 1 VC continue to play and xCdoe give me the following error quite a few times

```
2013-01-21 22:16:07.901 TTBetaDev[678:c07] Warning: Attempt to present <MainMenuViewController: 0x7e02f40> on <BonusViewController: 0x7ecbfa0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Below is a screenshot of my storyboard in case I havent explained the layout well enough.

How should this be set up to allow the navigation I would like? A what steps will I need to take to apply that to the what I already have built in the storyboards? Or will I have to re-do all my storyborad work?

I tried apples VC documentation but I couldnt understand what relates to what Im trying to do.

COuld someone please help explain this to me

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have segues going forwards AND backwards. You shouldn't do this.

e.g. Look and Main and VC 2.

You have a segue going from Main to VC 2. This means that Main will present VC 2 as a modal view controller.

When Main does this though it is still on the stack underneath VC2.

Then you have a segue from VC2 to Main. This means that VC2 will create a new Main and present it modally too. If you continue using the app you will have multiple instances of main and all the other VCs and memory consumption will rocket.

What you need to do is delete ALL the segues that go backwards. (i.e. like the one from VC2 to Main)

Then when you want to get back to main from VC2 you have to dismiss VC2.

i.e.

in Main...

```
//present VC2
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"VC2Segue" sender:nil];

//dismiss VC2
[self dismissViewController:vc2ViewControllerInstance];
```

or in VC2...

```
//dismiss VC2 from itself
[self dismissViewController:self];
```

The main thing though is that you can't use segues to go backwards.

TL:DR

Nothing should segue INTO Main. Any segues that go into the left hand side of main should be deleted and dealt with properly.

Comment: Thank you very much that makes perfect sense when you out it like that.

Comment: Also to reset a displayed viewcontroller i've been creating a UIButton in the viuewcontroller and making a segue from that button back to the same view controller. Given your explanation and specifically the memory issue, this is probly a bad idea. How should i "reset" a view controller's contents and values back to what theywere when it was first loaded?

Comment: I'd create a method called "displayDefaultContent" or something. In here you set all the default data. Then in viewDidLoad you run [self displayDefaultContent]; and on your button press you run [self displayDefaultContent]; and anywhere else you need to reset the view you can do this.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to easily query the center points of all the imageviews on the storyboad so they can be put back. Seems likely I could enumerate through the objects and store their center points in an array not sure how to do that yet but does that sound like im on the right track?

Comment: Hmm... you could create an NSObject subclass that contains a UI element (like a UIImageView) and a default setting (maybe a dictionary or just a CGPoint whatever). Then when the view loads you can iterate through the UIImageViews and store the setting in the NSObject and put the NSObjects into an array. Or something.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are moving stuff around on the screen and need to reset them you could consider using a CGAffineTransform to move them. Then you just need to set the transform on each view to CGAffineTransformIdentity and everything will go back to where they started.